# Brain anatomy- hippocampus and amygdala positions

Tags: neuroanatomy

I'm trying to teach myself about the structure of the brain and am slightly confused as to whether the hippocampus and amygdala are parts of the temporal lobe or whether they are just parts of the cerebrum which are close to the temporal lobe. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hippocampus and the amygdala is neither part of the temporal lobe or the cerebrum, it part of the limbic system located at the top of the brain stem and is cover by the cerebral cortex that the temporal lobe is a part of.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was wondering- are the hippocampus and amygdala at least part of the forebrain? And are they both part of the limbic system? Is the whole of the limbic system part of the forebrain? Thank you for your help :)